# how to Access Local to EJB module from My Web APP With Enterprise App

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I have JSF Managed bean (It's Name =indexbean1) and It's Code As Follow:

```
 package ir.ac.imamreza.Client;

 import ir.ac.imamreza.common.ProductServiceLocal;
 import javax.ejb.EJB;
 import javax.inject.Named;
 import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
 import javax.naming.InitialContext;

 /**
 *
 * @author Avarcom
 */
 @Named(value = "indexbean1")
 @RequestScoped
 public class Indexbean1 {
 private String name;
 private int price;
 private int count;
 private String desc;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }



    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }


    @EJB
    private  ProductServiceLocal ProductService1;
    public void  Add()         
    {
        ProductService1.Add(name,price, count, desc);
    }

    public Indexbean1() {
    }
 }
```

And I have Class That It has Local Interface of Class "ProductServiceLocal" In My Shop Module  as follow:

```
package ir.ac.imamreza.common;

 import java.util.List;
 import javax.ejb.Local;

 /**
 *
 * @author One God
 */
 @Local
 public interface ProductServiceLocal {

    List<Product> getallproduct();
    public int BuyProduct(long id,long number);
    public void Add(String name, int price,int count,String desc);

 }
  ///////////////////////////
```

and This that My EJB Modul   that Implement My Add method in My EJB

```
  ////////////////////


 package ir.ac.imamreza.Shop;
 import ir.ac.imamreza.common.Product;
 import ir.ac.imamreza.common.ProductServiceRemote;
 import java.math.BigDecimal;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.List;
 import javax.ejb.Stateless;
 import java.sql.*; 

@Stateless(mappedName="ir.ac.imamreza.Shop.ProductService")
 public class ProductService implements ProductServiceLocal,ProductServiceRemote { 

    @Override
    public int BuyProduct(long id,long number)
    {
        int result;
         dataaccess da=new dataaccess();
         result=da.exec("update tbl_product set count=count-"+number+" where id='"+id+"'");
          da.Close();
         return result;
    }
     public void Add(String name, int price,int count,String desc)
      {
          dataaccess da=new dataaccess();
           da.exec("INSERT INTO tbl_product (name,count,price,Description) VALUES      
   ("+name+","+price+","+count+","+desc+")");
          da.Close();
      }

 }
```

I Added My EJB and MY WEB App For Accessing to My LOCAl method(ADD) ,but when i wan't to Deploy My App i faced with following Error:

```
SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app [WebClient] : Cannot resolve reference Local ejb-ref name=ir.ac.imamreza.Client.Indexbean1/ProductService1,Local 3.x interface =ir.ac.imamreza.common.ProductServiceLocal,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session
..
```

I think That My Web APP can not connect to MY EJB ,For this problem I Added Web APP and EJAB to One Enterprise APP,But again i faced with these error ,
Plz Kindly help me and Thanks before

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Error is very clear. In your JSF, you are attempting a field based EJB injection which does not exist.

Now, here is the rule for field based injection:

> For field based resource injection, JNDI name is resolved to (package
>   + Classname)/(EJB injection variable name) and it tries to find that in your local app(war,ear..). So, in this case, it is being resolved
>   to (ir.ac.imamreza.Client).(Indexbean1)/ProductService1 which does not
>   exist in your ear or war.

Regards
Ravi